# How to change the Qt version used by TeXstudio in elementary os Freya?

Tags: elementary-os, qt, latex, texstudio

I have installed TexStudio 2.8.8. When I open it, it says TeXStudio has been compiled with Qt 4.8.6 but running with Qt 4.7.3. Please get the correct runtime library.

when I checked in terminal with

```
qmake -v
```

I got the following output,

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.5 in /home/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86/lib
```

How do I resolve this issue?
(I am on elementary os Freya)

Comment: Have you poked around the files in `~/.config/texstudio/`? However, the app might not be able to change that - as apps have to be updated to use more up to date libs